# Is it possible to submit form in React without redirect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

When I submit form I get direct to black page or it gets redirected something like this

> ?name="..."&type="..."

but I want to stay in same component and update the component with out getting redirected according to the state change.

Route Code:

```
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Products from './pages/products';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>App Page</h1>
      <Route path="/">
        <Home />
        <Products />
      </Route>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Home Component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addProduct } from '../actions/shop.Action';

const Home = ({ addProduct }) => {
  let name;
  let type;

  const nameHandler = (e) => {
    name = e.target.value;
  };

  const typeHandler = (e) => {
    type = e.target.value;
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    addProduct({
      productName: name,
      productType: type,
    });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <h1>Add Product</h1>
      <label>Product Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="pname" onChange={nameHandler}  />
      <label>Product Type</label>
      <input type="text" name="ptype" onChange={typeHandler} />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  addProduct: (product) => dispatch(addProduct(product)),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(Home);
```

Product Component:

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux'



const Products = ({products}) =>{

 console.log(products)
    return(
        <div>
           {products.length?products:<p>No Products</p>} 
        </div>
    )
}


const mapStateToProps = (state) =>({
    products: state.shop
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Products);
```

Reducer or INITIAL STATE:

```
import { addProductType } from '../actionTypes/shop.actionTypes';


const INIT = [];


const Shop = (state = INIT, action) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case addProductType:
        const products = [...state]
        products.push(action.payload)
        return  [...state,...products]
    default:
        return state    
  }
};

export default Shop;
```

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BCvu.png)

video link : https://streamable.com/nauewl

Comment: Can you reproduce the same issue on codesandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-feistel-i1h6s?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: State was array but I got some error so I had to change to object .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a couple of issues with your code. Here is the fixed version:

https://codesandbox.io/s/recursing-meitner-80qo0?file=/src/pages/Home.jsx

Your reducer was incorrect. You were using an `object` but expecting an array in your `Products` UI. Also, the initial state should have been an array.

**Note:** You can use an object if you want but isn't really necessary unless you are planning to have a huge list and add crud functionality to your application. Also, an object doesn't have a `lenght` property. You would've used `Object.keys` in that case.

```
import { addProductType } from "../actionTypes/shop.actionTypes";

const INIT = [];

const Shop = (state = INIT, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case addProductType:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default Shop;
```

The initial state should've been an array and upon every addition of an item, the previous state has to be merged with the currently added item and return an `array`.

In your product UI, you were not iterating through the products. You need `map` to do that. (You can use other methods but this is the most recommended way, also, you cannot use something like `forEach` because it doesn't return anything).

Correction:

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const Products = ({ products }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {products.length > 0
        ? products.map((product, index) => (
            <div key={index}>
              <span>{product.productName}</span>
              <span>{product.productType}</span>
            </div>
          ))
        : "No products"}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  products: state.shop
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Products);
```

**Note:** For the key prop, it is always suggested to have a unique identifier for each list item. Index will work in this case since the current scope of the application doesn't deal with list manipulation.

And lastly, in your `Home` component, you were using local variables instead of state variables to capture input values. Which is fine, but, doesn't allow you to keep track of values and manipulate them for any other use cases like validation.

Comment: Yes , It worked . Can you please explain where did I go wrong?

Comment: @RunzunShrestha Done. Please upvote the answer if it helped you. Might benifit other readers as well.

Comment: I can see you used state on this. Is it necessary? or I can do it in my way as well.....const Home = ({ addProduct }) => {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("");
  const [type, setType] = React.useState("");

  const nameHandler = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  const typeHandler = (e) => {
    setType(e.target.value);
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addProduct({
      productName: name,
      productType: type
    });
  };

Comment: You can use local variables, but your component will not re-render. Which in turn will not allow you to do anything useful with your component. For example, consider you want to show validation errors in your form as the use is typing, you'll want your component to re-render. 

Read more about controlled components: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html